# SharePoint 2019 Solutions with sandboxed code are disabled

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sandbox-solution

I have a SharePoint 2019 server with a single server farm role. I have enabled the sandbox code service following these steps: [enable-sandbox-solutions-on-sharepoint-2016](https://sharepoint.handsontek.net/2016/08/14/enable-sandbox-solutions-on-sharepoint-2016/)
When I upload a sandbox solution containing a workflow the activate button is enabled. When I click activate I get the ULS error: "Solutions with sandboxed code are disabled"
And on screen "Activation of solutions with sandboxed code has been disabled"

any ideas?

When I create a new Sandbox solution in Visual Studio and upload this to my site I can activate the solution.

Are workflows no longer allowed in Sandbox solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, the code-based sandbox solutions are no longer going to work in SP 2019. It's one of the most promitent things removed in the latest sever version of the product:

> After careful consideration, we've decided to also remove support for
> code-based sandbox solutions in SharePoint Server 2019. Customers are
> recommended to explore SharePoint add-ins as an alternative, which are
> fully supported for both SharePoint on-premises and SharePoint.

[Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-from-sharepoint-server-2019#:%7E:text=After%20careful%20consideration%2C%20we%27ve,SharePoint%20on%2Dpremises%20and%20SharePoint.)

Comment: Are Sandbox solutions with a workflow considered as code-based then?

Comment: As long as a workflow is part of a sandbox package - then yes. I think, even if a workflow has no custom actions, it's still going to be considered code-based.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Denis, as mentioned this feature has already been removed in SP 2019.